Can I force the type of merge allowed per branch in GitHub
We have branches main, staging and sometimes features branches feature/*. I want to ensure that feature branches always get squashed into staging and that staging only gets merged into main.
I.e. I want to prevent staging to be squashed into main and lose the history, but I cannot disable squash merges completely since I want to use them for merging feature branches.
Any idea how I can make this work?
I've set staging to require a linear history, but cannot force the opposite on main.
I saw Set pull request merge options per branch but my issue is a bit different (and it has no answer to go from)
